# Firebase add new child with specified name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database

[image]

I'd like to add new users to database keeping that format. I've tried this:

```
   //Store data in database
    Firebase usersRef = ref.child("Users");
    Map<String, String> userData = new HashMap<String, String>();

    userData.put("Nombre", name);
    userData.put("Password", pass);
    userData.put("Confirmed", "FALSE");
    userData.put("Email", mail);

    usersRef.setValue(name);
    usersRef = ref.child("Users").child(name);
    usersRef.setValue(userData);
```

The problem is whenever I add a new user, the previous one is overwritten.

Comment: can i have the full example for make database like that way ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It happens because you are using:

```
Firebase usersRef = ref.child("Users");
usersRef.setValue(name);
```

In this way you will push the value in `url/Users` removing the previous value.

Check the [doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html):

> Using setValue() will overwrite the data at the specified location, including any child nodes.

To add a new user without removing the previous one , just remove this line:

```
//usersRef.setValue(name);
```

In this way you will push the value in `url/Users/myName` without overriding other values.

Comment: Thanks. What should I use then?

Comment: @Aldridge1991 Updated the answer

Answer (score 6):

[Firebase Database Push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVeyv.png)

```
[FirebaseDatabase mydb =][2] FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mDatabase = mydb.getReference().child("Dealers").child(dealerId).child("Stock").child(stockAddDate);

Map<String, String> userData = new HashMap<String, String>();

userData.put("Product_Name", productName);
userData.put("Holding_Stock", holdingStock);
userData.put("Primary_Stock", primaryStock);
mDatabase.push().setValue(userData);
```

Just use "PUSH" before `setValue`.

Comment: what is -klaxOUQNJjWf0OaF-77, and how to avoid this values?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. I am using model class instead of Hash

```
mFirebaseDatabase.child(name);
mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseDatabase.child(name);
FirebaseDatabase.setValue(name);
FirebaseDatabase.setValue(user);
```