# Firebase realtime Database Hashmap overwrites data

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

In short, when I click on the marker it must register the user id of the user who clicked on "Partecipanti". The problem is that if the first user is saved regularly when a second user clicks, this overwrites the first one. How can I solve it?

```
 @Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {

    LatLng latLon = marker.getPosition();

    for(Incontro incontro : Incontri) {
        if (latLon.equals(incontro.getLatlng())) {

            if(){
                Toast.makeText(Cercaincontro.this, "You are already attending this event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {

                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Incontro").child(incontro.getIncontroidId());
                HashMap<String, Object> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
                String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                hashMap1.put("userid", firebaseUser.getUid());

                reference.child("Partecipanti").child(uid).setValue(true);

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try saving it somewhere else for each user.

Comment: I need to save all users inside "Partecipanti". Any tip? @AliasCartellano

Comment: Add another child to "Partecipanti" for each new user.

Comment: Like what, can you explain with code?

Comment: Try [pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44320600/16653700) the userids into "partecipanti".

Comment: Like this? `reference.child("Partecipanti").push().setValue(hashMap1);`

Comment: I think that'll work.

Comment: Not work, look: https://imgur.com/a/HUkaQR0 I need all the users in "Partecipanti" just the users

Comment: You may need to take the `HashMap` from firebase and add to the `HashMap` retrieved before uploading.

Comment: How can i do this thing with code?

Comment: [Retrieve the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=36B6BDC13DA84F37AC523F23772B337D#java_6) then store the id to the `HashMap` and upload the `HashMap`.

Comment: Could you make an answer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @AliasCartellano's solution to pushing data into the Realtime Database will work, please note a pushed ID it's not the best option to identify a user. Why? Because every time you call [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()), another unique key is generated.

Since I see in your screenshot that you store some long IDs, other than the pushed IDs, the ones that start with `-` (minus), I assume you're using authentication. That being said, a more recommended way to store user data would be like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- $uid
            |
            --- //user data
```

And to add data to such a structure, you should use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
reference.child("Partecipanti").child(uid).setValue(hashMap1);
```

This means, that each user will write data under a separate location since each UID is unique. So in this way, you cannot overwrite the data.

**Edit:**

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- $uid: true
       |
       --- $uid: true
```

And in code:

```
reference.child("Partecipanti").child(uid).setValue(true);
```

**Edit2:**

To be able to write an object that looks like this, please use the following lines code:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("addressorganizz", "messina");
data.put("cittaorg", "messin");
//As as much data as you need.
reference.child("Partecipanti").child(uid).setValue(data);
```

**Edit3:**

```
//Data
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("addressorganizz", "messina");
data.put("cittaorg", "messin");

String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(); 
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference("Incontro")
    .child(incontro.getIncontroidId())
    .child(uid);  
reference.setValue(data);
```

Comment: We are approaching the solution but I want that in this as in this photo:https://imgur.com/a/w2WPTzV  there are only the IDs of the users so without anything inside. How can I do?

Comment: In a nutshell I would like the users IDs to be the children of "Partecipanti"

Comment: In that case, you shoould use `"CKXD...ats1": true`. There is no way you can have a child without a value. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Where should I put this "true"?

Comment: As a value to the uid key, right?

Comment: Inside the firebase or in the code?

Comment: Inside Firebase Database. See my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: In addition to the value, I have to insert a key

Comment: So the UID would be the key and true, the value. Otherwise, you have to do it your way. Is it clear now?

Comment: I don't understand what I have to do, but I don't think it works

Comment: Please check again my updated answer and tell me if it works.

Comment: It does not save the information inside like before: https://imgur.com/a/5TK1XTw. Updated question with your code, can you check?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Show me how would you like the data in the database. Provide a concrete screenshot.

Comment: I want like this: https://imgur.com/a/PXh9rNj

Comment: WHat is 166135...? Are you generating it?

Comment: Is the marker on the google maps and is incontro in the for

Comment: So you don't use the UID anymore? I'm having a hard time understand what you need.

Comment: I wrote in the question what I would like to do

Comment: In that case, my answer solves your problem.

Comment: No, because it's not what I would like. I would like that when I click on the marker to insert in "Participants" the id of the users who have clicked it. As you did it is not like that. Like this image https://imgur.com/a/PXh9rNj

Comment: I will try only one more time. I'll edit my answer right away.

Comment: But besides that, I cannot see in that picture the UID. Where would you like to be added?

Comment: Incontro-> 166135... -> "partecipanti-> "here"

Comment: Check my latest update. Is it ok now?

Comment: Like this is not inside https://imgur.com/a/YwSelup

Comment: This is what it does `Incontro-> 166135... -> "partecipanti-> "uid"`, right? Show me a concrete screen and the exact code you're using **now**.

Comment: `reference.child("Partecipanti").child(uid).setValue(hashMap1);` When i click I'm already inside 166135 ... so in here I just have to add "Participants" and inside the users

Comment: Then remove those call only use `    reference.child("Partecipanti").child(uid).setValue(data);`. Is it ok now?

Comment: `reference.child("Partecipanti").child(uid).setValue(true);` like this seems to work. https://imgur.com/a/av4C7Ns

Comment: But I have to check that if the user who clicked already participates in this event then he is inside the "Participants" field that Toast that I put comes out otherwise it is inserted in the "Participants". How can i do?

Comment: Edited question with new code, because i don't know if with this database can do this thing

Comment: Check my latest update. Is it ok now?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/b9dOMLc Not work look

Comment: Use **only** the code in `Edit3:`, nothing else. Nothing from your code, nothing from my earlier edits. Remove this line of `hashMap1.put("userid", firebaseUser.getUid());` code. Is ok?

Comment: WIth your code not save nothing in my database, it's ok llike before i guess. I need help with the check "if"